# Assigning a special ID to similar latitude and longitude

Tags: r, categories

I have a time-series dataset with latitude, longitude, and temprature data. I want to categorize the data by assigning a special ID to similar latitude and longitide values.

```
Sr.    Date       Longitude    Latitude    Temp      ID
1     1/1/1981       79          29.3       281       1
2     1/1/1981       78          29.3       271       2
3     1/1/1981       77          29.3       275       3
4     1/1/1981       76          29.3       282       4
5     2/1/1981       79          29.3       285       1
6     2/1/1981       78          29.3       283       2
7     2/1/1981       77          29.3       275       3
8     2/1/1981       76          29.3       283       4
```

i expect the data to have a special ID for similar locations.

```
Sr.    Date       Longitude    Latitude    Temp      ID
1     1/1/1981       79          29.3       281       1
5     2/1/1981       79          29.3       285       1
```

Comment: Hello,  can you define what you mean by "similar" lat and long?  Do they need to be identical to one decimal place, for example?  If we can define what the 'bins' are then categorising the results is relatively straightforward.

Comment: Hi, similar means identical to two decimal places. You have understood it right.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
    group_by(Longitude, Latitude) %>%
    mutate(id = cur_group_id()) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Looking at your sample data and criteria that looks like it should do the job.

Comment: No worries.  If that solved your problem please click the 'tick' next to my answer to mark it as "accepted".  If not, add a comment and I'll try to improve it!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I explored it a bit further and it worked using the code as follows: mutate(DF3, x = paste(lon, lat, sep ="_"))